# How to create picture grid without spacing/padding? (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, css, grid, portfolio

I am working on a WordPress site and there is something that I just can't figure out no matter how hard I try. I want to have a grid similar to this (http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/origin/) but more like this: (http://themeforest.net/item/hercules-portfolio-business-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/5124743). You'll see that in the hercules theme the grid is only at the top of the page. I want to do something similar to that at the middle of the page. Unfortunately I cannot switch themes to get that one function. So I wanted to know how I would create my own version. Can someone point me in the right direction?

P.s. the grid does not need to have any fancy zoom animation and doesn't even have to be linkable. Just static pictures like that in a grid of 4x2. No spacing or padding or margins between the images. And I contacted the designer of that theme and he mentioned that it is not a plugin that does it. It's custom CSS3. He wasn't any more helpful then that though :/

Comment: You should take screenshots and add the relevant code here. If those links ever change (and they will), this Question won't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use an unordered list to contain the images, float the list items and apply a 25% width. The images then need a 100% width, and max-width 100% and height: auto a for responsive layout. The images you upload would need to have the same height dimension (or you could set a fixed height on the list items, but risk losing some image content).

```
ul#picture_grid {

list-style: none;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;

}

#picture_grid li {

float: left;
width: 25%;

}

#picture_grid img {

display: block;
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;

}
```